# Xamarin unable to read information from Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and to C# I write code in Xamarin for Android only

NuGet packages: Firebase Database.net 4.2.0

following 2 codes are responsible for getting data from Firebase RealTime Database

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int RecordMathGame { get; set; }
    public int RecordMathGameMinus { get; set; }
    public int RecordPuzzleGame { get; set; }
    public int RecordMemoryGame { get; set; }
}
```

```
public static class Setting
{
    internal const string FireBaseDatabaseUrl = "my url";
    internal const string FireBaseSeceret = "my secret";
}
```

```
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient(Setting.FireBaseDatabaseUrl, new FirebaseOptions
{
    AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(Setting.FireBaseSeceret)
});
```

the `GetEmployee()` function is responsible for getting user data via Email.

This function gives an error. It reads information from the Realtime Database, but after reading it gives an error:

```
public async void GetEmployee()
 {
    await firebase.Child(nameof(EmployeeModel)).Child(employeeModel.Email).OnceAsync<EmployeeModel>();
 }
```

gives the following error (pictured)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you split GetEmployee's long line of code to small parts, to check which part actually throws the exception? Also, the email seems to be bad/badly formatted, because it has "@gmail" without ".com".

Comment: The .OnceAsync<T>() returns an object, that you are not saving. Try that. (https://bolorundurowb.dev/posts/31/using-the-firebase-realtime-database-with-net)

Comment: line in GetEmployee() function: OnceOnceAsync<EmployeeModel>() throws an error

Comment: You can try to sign out from Firebase console and sign back in again.